# Remove upper margin bootstrap 4 navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have an issue with the bootstrap 4 navbar - I need to remove the white space that appears above the nav bar but I can't understand why it's not working. It looks like the following when rendered:

[image: bootstrap 4 nav issue]

It appears by default it adds in this white space, does anybody know what i've done wrong here?

Code is below:

```
<div class="row site-hero d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <div class="col navbar-row w-100">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md nomergy-nav">
                <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                 </button>
                 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img height="30" src="/themes/nomergy/assets/images/2018/logo.png"> 
                 </a>
                 <a class="nav-link mob-profile" href="/login">
                    <i class="far fa-user nav-link"></i>
                </a>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto navbar-default">
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/about">My Links</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                 </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

Comment: row inside row, why ?

Comment: removed in question - minor oversight

Comment: Kinda hard to say without being able to see the other CSS you're using. But, usually I would expect a 'nav' element to be the parent container of the nav. If you have a link to your page or a jsfiddle that would make troubleshooting easier.

Comment: http://labs.nomergy.twomatesmedia.com.au/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Note:*** *Using negative margin is not prefered ideally*

In your `home.css` file you have,

```
.site-hero {
    ...
    min-height:750px;
    ...
}
```

Either remove `min-height:750px;` or if you can't remove it please override using,

```
.site-hero {
    min-height:auto;
}
```

[image]